# xubuntu 20.04.2 install SPROM + errors never stop

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, xubuntu

Why is all of a sudden xubuntu 20.04 so buggy?  The errors upon installation never stop.  Trying to install on my computer which has run xubuntus from 16.04 then 18.04 without problems.  All of a sudden 20.04 has never ending problems.

Problem 1 was that all of a sudden it said my harddrive was hibernating under Windows-10/64bit.  Even when I did a complete shutdown.  So I found the hibernate/off function for Windows and presumeably it worked.

Problem 2 is unsolved. Now it says "unsupported SPROM"  then it prints "this is not a typewriter" 50+ times down my screen.  Also "unable to find a medium container for a live filesystem".

Attempted to boot from a Linux DVD iso with xubuntu 20.04.2 on it.  All of a sudden xubuntu seems to have gone back to 1983 with this typewriter and SPROM stuff.  Why such a buggy release?

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of 1983, the "Not a typewriter" message (or ENOTTY) is an error code defined in the `errno.h` found on many Unix systems dating back to the 70s and is now used to indicate that an invalid input/output control number was specified in an ioctl system call, most likely in that "unsupported SPROM". If you have an Nvidia graphics controller in your computer, you'll need to edit the boot to use `nomodeset`.

Here's how to do it:

0. If you can boot the machine to a semi-usable state, open a terminal
1. Edit the `/etc/default/grub` file as root:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Look for the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line, which probably looks something like:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   Add `nomodeset` after `splash` so that you have this:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
   ```

   ***Note:** The order of the flags are unimportant, but adding it to the end makes sense.*
3. Save the file
4. Reboot

This should give you a computer rather than "not a typewriter"

Comment: computer uses an AMD Radeon HD 5700 graphics card.  Also I can't boot the machine under xubuntu DVD to any state.  Booting from a DVD it gives this error; thus nothing is installed.  It ran Ubuntus and xUbuntu's with no problems from ver 16.04 and 18.04.  Why is 20.04 so buggy?

Comment: @NicholasBourbaki 20.04 has a new kernel with it.  Depending on how old your hardware is, there is a chance that the hardware may not be supported.  I would recommend that you edit your question and add in what type of hardware you are trying to install Ubuntu to.  Also, I have seen one about the SPROM https://superuser.com/questions/1200994/no-sprom-available-error-when-installing-ubuntu-from-usb where they are suggesting to disable the WLAN in BIOS then install the system or drivers.  If that is the case, then 20.04 may not support your WLAN out of the box.

Comment: That is quite interesting.  My computer is quite old.  I have another 'dead' one {computer} which uses a much better motherboard.  Also my current motherbord will socket a max of 8GB.  Also this computer will not boot from an external DVD drive connected via USB.  It runs Windows 10 just fine tho.

Comment: Tried to boot on a much newer machine.  This is my MSI GS60 (Ghost 60) laptop which also duel boots with Windows-10: 64bit/ xubuntu 18.04 w/o problem.  Same error: "Not a typewriter" appears 50x erasing all previous error messages.   Either my installation DVD is bad or it's the 20.04.2   Maybe I should try the 20.04.1  and would luv to know how I can do the checksum.  BTW, the DVD verified successfully upon burn.

Comment: @NicholasBourbaki It is quite possible to have a bad download.  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview   Also, you will find the SHA256SUMS https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04.2.0/

Comment: While I don't have a bad download, it's possible that I may have somehow burnt a bad iso DVD copy as my version of Nero is extremely old.  They asking me to upgrade.  I did the sha256 check and the #'s matched.